# Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi 1

Tags: raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 and was wanting to install Ubuntu on it.

I'm relatively new to both the Pi and Linux, so I was hoping for help on my issue as well as tutorials for the beginners on linux use.

Thank you to anyone who replies! Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: Off topic operating systems are off topic ;)

Comment: I'm more interested in Ubuntu than I am the other OS, which is why I came here, but was hoping to get help on both anyway

Comment: Ubuntu will not run on the raspberry 1. Raspbian will...